# Difference of random variables subject to non-negative values

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, expected-value

This is probably close to trivial for stats experts. Yet, although having searched the web for quite a while now, I have not been able to come up with a satisfactory answer.

Given two (approximately) Gaussian random variables, $u$ and $v$, what is the PDF and the expectation value of $u – v$ given the prior knowledge that $u – v \ge 0$? I remember vaguely having seen something along this lines based on Bayesian inference. However, now I seem unable to locate this resource.

Comment: Would more usually be described as a distribution _conditional_ on $u–v \ge 0$.  'Prior knowledge' would be of a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, I don't think you need Bayesian stats here.

If $u \sim$ Normal($\mu_u, \sigma^2_u$) and $v \sim$ Normal($\mu_v, \sigma^2_v$) are **independent** random variables, then $w = u - v \sim$ Normal($\mu_u - \mu_v, \sigma^2_u + \sigma^2_v)$. If you are given that $w \ge 0$ (i.e. $u-v \ge 0 $), what you have is a [truncated Normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) $(\mu_u - \mu_v, \sigma^2_u + \sigma^2_v)$ from 0 to infinity (using the notation given in the Wiki article $a = 0$ and $b=\infty$).